# how to get google workspace endpoint list from a google script

Tags: google-workspace

I'm trying to get the list of Google Workspace endpoints(desktops, laptops), but I can't find a way to do that. I managed to get the list of mobile devices through the following way:

```
page = AdminDirectory.Mobiledevices.list('my_customer',{
    orderBy: 'lastSync',
    maxResults: 100,
    pageToken: pageToken    
  });
```

Is there a similar way to list endpoints?